# Entity-Record Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Its work fine but when user change 'ProductDTO.Property1' field name to 'ProductDTO.Property2' - via firebug, DTO's Property2 setting as client request. In the meantime, I'm not wondering about DTOs but when i map an entity to page for editing, client can change db records.

I want to protect some properties with role. Users cannot change but admins can

eg. Have any solution like this;

```
[Secure(Role="Admin")]
public string Property2 { get; set; }
```

DTO:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

In aspx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CmTest.Web.Controllers.ProductController.ProductFormViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
<label for="Product_Property1">Property1:</label>
<div>
    <%= Html.TextBox("ProductDTO.Property1", (ViewData.Model.ProductDTO != null) ? ViewData.Model.ProductDTO.Property1 : "")%>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Controller:

```
[Transaction]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ProductFormViewModel viewModel = ProductFormViewModel.CreateProductFormViewModel();
    viewModel.ProductDTO = productRepository.GetDTO(id);

    return View(viewModel);
}

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Transaction]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductDTO productDTO)
{
    //debugging
}

public class ProductFormViewModel
{
    private ProductFormViewModel() { }

    public static ProductFormViewModel CreateProductFormViewModel()
    {
        ProductFormViewModel viewModel = new ProductFormViewModel();

        return viewModel;
    }

    public ProductDTO ProductDTO { get; internal set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardly understand what you are asking but if you are worried about mass assignment you could exclude Property2 from binding:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "Property2")]ProductDTO productDTO)
```

or even better use `Include` to make a white-list of bindable properties.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, its look like right but compiler wont throw error when i change property name. Thanks again.

Comment: No, the compiler won't throw error, it will exclude the property from binding at runtime, even if someone tweaks the HTTP request and tries to set the value, the property will always have it's default value.

Comment: Thank you, i guess only this solution fixing the security hole.